# Allow node-webkit to be multi-window?

Tags: node-webkit, nw.js

As we know, if set a name in package.json, we always open a unique node-webkit window. How to allow node-webkit to be multi-windows? 
Mean that if I run nw once, I can get a new nw app.

Comment: your question is not clear!

Answer (score 1):

I think he is talking about how nwjs is managing the windows. When you open a new window through the main node, the second window doesn't have access to nwjs. You can't use any code of nwjs working in the new window with a external url.

```
    nw.Window.open(link,{}, function(new_win) {
         new_win.requestAttention(true); 
         new_win.setResizable(false);
     });
```

Here the new window will appear and will flash in the taskbar, but If I want to make it flash again thru the opened window is not possible because the new windows has not access to nwjs.